# Randomly select list from list of lists in python depending on weights

Tags: python, list, numpy, random

I have a list of lists, where each list is associated with a score/weight. I want to produce a new list of lists by randomly selecting from the first one so that those with higher scores will appear more often. The line below works fine when `population` is just a normal list. But I want to have it for a list of lists.

```
population = [['a','b'],['b','a'],['c','b']]
list_of_prob = [0.2, 0.2, 0.6]

population = np.random.choice(population, 10, replace=True, p=list_of_prob)
```

This will give the output `ValueError: a must be 1-dimensional`

Comment: @Chicony you should mention in the question that it's not necessary should be `numpy`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of passing the actual list, pass a list with indexes into the list.

`np.random.choice` already allows this, if you pass an int `n` then it works as if you passed `np.arange(n)`.

So

```
choice_indices = np.random.choice(len(population), 10, replace=True, p=list_of_prob)
choices = [population[i] for i in choice_indices]
```

Comment: `TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index`

Comment: @roganjosh use `range(len(population))`

Comment: This will actually work like a charm, just if you do `choice = [population[i] for i in choice_index]`, instead of `choice = population[choice_index]` as `choice_index` is a `list`

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev still the same error. It comes from line `choice = population[choice_index]`

Comment: @roganjosh: sorry, I didn't notice you were getting 10 values, assumed 1. Will edit.

Comment: Now it's fixed :)